# How do I disable the selected file overlay in the file explorer?

Tags: nautilus, gui

When I open a file explorer window and select an item, a yellow overlay appears in the bottom of the window. The overlay moves to avoid the cursor. How do I disable this feature?

Example image:

[image]

Comment: can only be disabled by altering the source of nautilus. Here am currently testing not disabling but making it disappear on mouseover